# How can I prove the integral exists and has an upper and lower bound for the sums for a discontinuous function?

Tags: real-analysis

We did alot of practice with continuous functions and finding the upper and lower Riemann sums but have not done any examples with discontinuous functions. Specifically, I do not know how I can find the upper and lower Riemann sums and prove that it is integrable for this function:

$f(x) = \begin{cases}
3 & x=0 \\
1 & x\neq 0 \\
\end{cases}$
from $[0,1]$.

I am not sure how I can go about this because it looks like at first glance, both the Upper and Lower Riemann sums are identical since nothing changes and it is a horizontal line. I know that you can prove integrability by saying the absolute difference of the two sums are less than $\epsilon$. But I do not know how I can even start creating the sums for either. All I know for sure is that the integral is just $1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with the definition. Partition the interval first; as the function is constant except on the boundary, this partition doesn't really matter at all. (Beyond the fact that this will turn out to be Riemann integrable, in which case it really won't matter.) Given $\epsilon>0$, we can just take $0 < \epsilon < x_2 < ... < x_{n-1} < 1$ as our partition, and say the difference between the $x_n$ gets small.

On every interval, the supremum and infimum of $f$ is 1, except on the first. Here, the sup is 3, while the inf is 1. But the width of the interval is $\epsilon$, making the contribution to the upper sum just $3\epsilon$. The contribution everywhere else is $1-\epsilon$. The lower sum is just 1.

Given $\epsilon$ can be made arbitrarily small, the integral converges, showing this function is Riemann integrable with an integral of 1.